# Java Rmi database connection?

Tags: java, mysql, rmi

I am trying to get data from `mysql` database by `rmi`,
When the client request the service from the server and trying to connect to db to get data
NO Suitable driver Exception rise !
or

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

**(Implementation Class)imp.java:**

```
public class imp extends java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject implements inter {
 ...
connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "root", "root");
public String getName() throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
    String name = "none";
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select ....");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            name = rs.getString("f_name");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return name;
   }
}
```

**(Interface)inter.java:**

```
public interface inter extends java.rmi.Remote {
    public String getName() throws java.rmi.RemoteException, SQLException;
}
```

(Server)Server.java:

```
public Server() throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException {
    server_object = new imp();
    Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:1099/myserv", server_object);
}
```

**(Client) client.java:**

```
 myobject = (inter) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:1099/myserv");
 myobject.getName();
```

I Put the `mysqlconnector` library in the folder of classes
Any Help?

Comment: have u included driver in your classpath?
and why dont you use `Class.forName(your_driver)`

Comment: check this out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182282/how-to-install-jdbc-and-how-to-use-it-to-connect-to-mysql

and this as well

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql/2840358#2840358

Comment: Why? The JDBC interface already exists. Why write another one?

Comment: Thank you dears, You have not to use Class.forName in mysql_connector 5, Just use DriverManager.getConnection(url,un,ps)

Answer (score 0):

The exception :java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver,causes  whenever we forget to add jar file for mysql connector. pls add mysql connector jar file to your projects classpath, and run it.

Edited:

you can download it from here : http://code.google.com/p/find-ur-pal/downloads/detail?name=mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar& or from here : http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html

Answer (score 0):

Extract mysql_connector jar file into three folders in the classes folder.
 Like this : com folder, META-INF folder, and org folder.